# How do I check whether a type is derived from vector / list / deque?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-traits, c++-templates

I'm using C++20.
I was able to check if a type is **some** vector / deque / list as follows:

```
template <typename N> struct is_listish_trait {
  static constexpr bool value = 0;
};

/* These are listish specializations */
template <typename N, typename A> struct is_listish_trait<std::vector<N, A>> {
  static constexpr bool value = 1;
};

template <typename N, typename A> struct is_listish_trait<std::list<N, A>> {
  static constexpr bool value = 1;
};

template <typename N, typename A> struct is_listish_trait<std::deque<N, A>> {
  static constexpr bool value = 1;
};

template <typename T>
static constexpr bool is_listish = is_listish_trait<T>::value;

static_assert(!is_listish<int>);
static_assert(is_listish<std::vector<int>>);
```

(I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in C++20, now that we have `requires` expressions, etc.)

However, now what I want is for `is_listish` to accept classes that derive from vectors / lists / deques. For instance:

```
struct MyVec : public std::vector<int> { };
static_assert(is_listish<MyVec>); //This should be true
```

I'm not sure if this is possible. This is what I tried:

```
template <typename B, typename D>
  requires std::is_base_of_v<B, D>
struct is_listish_trait<D> {
  static constexpr bool value = 1;
};
```

However, the compiler complains that it cannot deduce B (which is understandable).

How can one do this?

Comment: This is not a good idea regardless of the language version. You should instead check for specific functions: `.begin()`, `.end()`, etc. C++20 has `std::ranges::input_range` and others for this purpose.

Comment: What exactly do you need this trait for? I am sure that if you condense your requirements down to the what you really need, there will be a matching standard concept for it.

Comment: For example, it looks like you want to test for the concept of a _sequence container_, but then the question is for what exactly you need the _sequence container_ requirement. Wouldn't any kind of input/forward range be sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @user17732522, I think I'd require a sequence container (that I can `resize`, iterate over, etc.)

Comment: Seems like XY problem as others commented. Regardless of whether it is XY problem or not, this cannot be done in the general case. It can only be done if the types you want to examine is "cooperative" and reexports the template arguments as member types and those member types are inherited and visible in the child classes.

Comment: You can just inherit form `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` instead of having a `static constexpr bool` member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `requires`, you might do:

```
template <typename T>
concept is_listish =
       requires(T t) { []<typename U, typename A>(std::vector<U, A>&){}(t); }
    or requires(T t) { []<typename U, typename A>(std::list<U, A>&){}(t); }
    or requires(T t) { []<typename U, typename A>(std::deque<U, A>&){}(t); }
    ;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EEWPq9ffc)

Comment: You could make it now allow conversion (from derived classes of `std::vector` if you also added `not std::derived_from` as a constraint to each lambda. Ah wait, that wouldn't properly handle types that can be implicitly converted to `std::vector` though, nevermind.

Comment: You can do it with pointers (`requires(std::add_pointer_t<T> p) { []<typename U, typename A>(const volatile std::vector<U, A>*){}(p); }`) to prevent considering conversions

Comment: This doesn't allow conversions (well, just derived-to-base, which is the whole point). Just take by `const&` instead of `&` to achieve the same thing as @Artyer's formulation (nobody cares about `volatile`).

Comment: Oh, I though initially that class with `operator vector<T>&` would trick, but in fact not :-)

Answer (score 1):

***Warning:** Deriving from a class whose destructor is neither virtual nor protected is a [Bad Idea](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-non-virtual). So this should not be considered for the standard containers. However, this answer could be adapted to custom containers whose destructors are virtual (or protected).*

> now what I want is for `is_listish` to accept classes that derive from vectors / lists / deques.

You could simply state exactly this in your `requires` clauses. You require that the type in question has a base class that is `std::vector`. You just need to specify suitable value and allocator types. Fortunately, `std::vector` supplies them as member types. (If those member types do not exist, then this specialization should not—and will not—apply.) *This approach will fail if a class has multiple base classes that provide these member types.*

```cpp
template <typename N>
  // This partial specialization applies only to classes derived from std::vector.
  requires std::is_base_of_v<
    std::vector<typename N::value_type, typename N::allocator_type>,
    N>
struct is_listish_trait<N> : std::true_type {};
```

Similarly for lists and deques.

Comment: *"Caveat"* for types deriving from several `std::vector`/`std::list`/`std::deque` which won't compile with ambiguous specialization.

Comment: <https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#exception-57>: I'm pretty sure noone is using a `std::vector` polymorphically (here the "bad idea" is `delete`ing a `std::vector`, which shouldn't have been dynamically allocated in the first place). This advice comes from a bygone era of OOP everywhere and isn't really relevant anymore.

Comment: @Artyer From the exception you linked to: *"but clearly document that further-derived objects must not be used polymorphically as `B`'s."* Where is this documentation for `std::vector`?